# User Specific Calendar on a Sub site

Tags: 2013, calendar, user, sharepoint-calendar

I'm fairly new to SharePoint 2013. I'm trying to add two calendars to one of my sub sites. The first calendar (calendar A) is a group calendar for upcoming events for 12 people. Anyone of the 12 people could be covering each event, and everyone can see all the upcoming events on Calendar A.

I would like to add another calendar, Calendar B. I want Calendar B to show each users specific events without having to change the view, i.e. when each user logs in, they automatically see the group calendar (Calendar A) and their own calendar (calendar B).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes both can be possible,

1. For Calendar A, choose group calendar while creating the calendar.
2. For calendar B, use filter **Me** in the calendar view.

Hope this can fulfill your purpose..

Comment: Would you know why when I try to set Calendar A as a Group Calendar, I get an Error Page that says, "Unable to retrieve 'Resource' field from the current list(Events)"

Comment: Pls elaborate the whole scenario, you are doing with Group Calendar.